# How to avoid showing "Save Success" message when there's an error message in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, validation-rule

I've a VF page which creates cases. It has lot of validation rules, workflows and approvals associated with it. When a user enters details to edit a 
 vf page which is in approval process (user is not the assigned approver), upon save, I get the message "Save success" along with "Record locked". How do I avoid showing Save success message when there's an error or when a validation rule fires. I want to just display the error message.  Please look at the below image firing a validation rule but it also shows Save success.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the messages in the `ApexPages.getMessages()` collection in your controller and whenever you find one or more messages with a severity of `ApexPages.Severity.ERROR` don't add your success message.